# Can we have just one APNs auth key for multiple push services providers?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

Can we use the same APNs auth key from multiple service providers? For example, I want to use the APNs auth key with Firebase Cloud Messaging and FlareLane.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. It is just an authentication credential.  There is nothing that ties the credential to a specific service